# Format Date Column in USQL

Tags: u-sql

I currently have the following date format: 
"2017-Jan-30 12:45:02:345 EST"

But I need the format to be "MM/dd/yyyy HH:mm:ss"

Does anyone know how to do this? The issue is in the Date string below

```
@input= 
   EXTRACT
     Date string,
     Name string,
     Location string
   FROM @in
   USING Extractor.Csv();

OUTPUT @input
TO @out
USING Outputters.Csv();
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do something like this:

```
@input=EXTRACT
[Date] String,
[Name] string,
[Location] string
FROM @in
USING Extractors.Csv();
```

and then in SELECT statement you format your Date column:

```
@result = SELECT 
DateTime.ParseExact([Date],"yyyy-MMM-dd hh:mm:ss:fff EST",null).ToString("MM/dd/yyyy HH:mm:ss") AS Date
Location,
Name
FROM @input
```

For more DateTime formats in c# you can check [this](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/standard/base-types/custom-date-and-time-format-strings)

Comment: Thanks for the responce but it is giving me an error, it is saying:

Comment: "Inner exception from user expression: String was not recognized as a valid DateTime."

Comment: "Error while evaluation expression DateTime.ParseExact(Date, "yyyy-MMM-dd hh:mm:ss:fff EST", null).ToString("MM/dd/yyyy HH:mm:ss")

Comment: Any idea why? Because after looking at the c# info you sent it looks about right

Comment: I know date doesn't show like this "[Date]" in the error, as it shows it like this "Date" but I have it written correctly in the code

Comment: Hi Eddy, as wBob edited my answer you should put HH instead of hh, thats for 24 hours clock.
So try  DateTime.ParseExact(Date, "yyyy-MMM-dd HH:mm:ss:fff EST", null).ToString("MM/dd/yyyy HH:mm:ss").
Also, are you sure that in your dataset column Date is always in that format?

Comment: Hi @Eddy42, if this answer has proved useful for you, would you consider marking it as the answer for Dragan please?

Comment: Hey sorry for the wait, the answer was almost fully correct as it still gave me an error. The EST was the issue, I Replace.EST with " " and that fixed the issue

Answer (score 0):

Maybe there are null values in your dataset so you can do something like this:

```
string.IsNullOrEmpty([Date]) ? null : DateTime.ParseExact(Date, "yyyy-MMM-dd HH:mm:ss:fff EST", null).ToString("MM/dd/yyyy HH:mm:ss") AS Date
```

Instead null you can return maybe default(DateTime), depends what you want.

Comment: @Eddy42 did you find this answer useful?